# Refreshing google sheet before a triggered function is activated

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-finance

I have a google sheet which has googlefinance formulas to get various values related to stocks. I have also created a function in app script which basically sends the value of the stocks in my email, and this function is set to trigger every month. Now, since the stock values are dynamic, I need the sheet to refresh everytime before the function for sending stock value in mail in triggered (so that I get the most recently updated value of stock from googlefinance). My query is:

1. Does the sheet refreshes by defualt when a function is called?
2. If not, How can I incorporate this feature in my code.

Thanks in advance

I am trying to search for a script (or any other way) to be added to my function to refresh the sheet before the values are shared over mail.

Comment: I've worked on Google Finance stocks in the past and the one thing I remember is that you cannot trust that they will be updated correctly.  I remember that they regularly don't update when there supposed to and sometimes it misses updates for several hours.  My experience suggests that you would be wise to find another more reliable source of information.  But of course that's just my opinion. But it's an opinion which forces me to avoid answering questions like this because I  believe that whatever you think you are accomplishing with their use... The reality is that you're probably not.

Comment: One other thing to note, functions in cells may not recalculate on a timed trigger if the spreadsheet is closed.  I tested it with a simple minute timed trigger where `=NOW()` is in a cell and the result are the same for each time the trigger is fired while the spreadsheet is closed.

Comment: @TheWizEd: Thanks for checking it. Could you please suggest a way how to get the sheet refreshed with updated values everytime before the function is run via triggered option.